# Test websocket server with junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, junit, tomcat7

Is JUnit able to test a websocket server, or is JUnit unable to complete this task and should another tool then be used to test a websocket server using Java? As of note the websocket server is hosted on a page served by Tomcat 7.0.53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing. However,  perhaps you can look at HTMLUnit which is API that allows you to programmatically access webpages.  You  can use that with JUnit to test your webpage.   You may also  want to look at JWebUnit that is based on HTMLUnit.   Something else that might be  helpful is that you can debug your webapp  using Eclipse.  You can either run the tomcat server  in eclipse or connect to a running server instance (You will need to set some options when starting tomcat if you do not run within  Eclipse)

Hope  this helps.

Comment: please expand on the confusing part so i can explain better. not being a prick just want to make it more clear to best help get an answer and help anyone else with a similar situation.